# VirtualBox doesn't restore saved Ubuntu machine state?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, windows-xp

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 inside Virtualbox on Windows XP Prof. Everything works fine. I'm running it at startup, but I have a problem with rebooting.

When I reboot my computer (WinXP) now the state of the virtual Ubuntu 12.04 isn't saved. After the reboot the virtualbox starts from the beginning.

Is there an option that Windows XP could send some signal to the virtual box to safely close the instance before the host reboot?

Comment: which version of VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug with [VirtualBox prior to versions 3.2.6](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5656) which has [bit me as well](https://superuser.com/a/428344/4377). This occurs if you have a non-standard install path

> The problem seems to be caused by not using the standard locations for
>   snapshots etc. Humour Virtualbox and allow it to keep all its files in
>   the standard directory, i.e. `c:\Documents and Settings\%user%\.VirtualBox\`.

---

The easy fix would be to upgrade VirtualBox - right now it's at 4.x version. Another alternative is to create symlinks, but that's a bit tricky.

And finally, to ensure all bases - I hope you've not set the VM to boot from the Live ISO - silly mistake but I've seen that happen.